# How can I use a first and second level states in components to avoid infinite render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Hi guys i have a specific problem with React with Hooks. Actually I have the following states:

- name (its a html input)
- brand (its a html input)
- color (its a hmtl input)
- variation (its a JS array)

But with the difference that 'variation' is an array of objects with the following structure:

```
variation: [{
   id: '123',
   name: 'variation 1',
   state: 'activate'
},{
   id: '345',
   name: 'variation 2',
   state: 'deactivate'
}]
```

The `variation` is a state of another Component and the variables, `name` and `state` are another input in the Component but I don't have any idea to handling with this (apply CRUD operations). I try to find a better solution but I'm compelled to use this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store `variation` in the parent component, and create a method to update it, based on the index. For example:

```
updateVariationName = (index, name) => {

   setVariation(prev => {
      //first, create a copy of the previous state
      //You should never modify the state directly
      let nuevo = [...prev];
      //Update the name
      nuevo[index].name = name;
      return nuevo;
  });
}
```

Map the variation array to create the input fields (and any other components needed), to use the function, for example:

```
variation.map( v, index ) => {
   <input onChange={ e=> updateVariationName(index, e.target.value) } />
}
```

You can create other functions to update the other properties.

There is a similar example [here](https://itnext.io/how-to-build-a-dynamic-controlled-form-with-react-hooks-2019-b39840f75c4f). It shows how to deal with your specific problem and some more complex tasks with forms.